# Find N similar records from pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a DataFrame in pandas and given the index of a particular row I want to select N most similar/duplicate records to the given index from the DataFrame. I have tried using DataFrame.duplicated() but it cannot take the index into consideration

```
students = [('jack', 34, 'Sydeny', 'Engineering'),
            ('Sachin', 30, 'Delhi', 'Medical'),
            ('Aadi', 16, 'New York', 'Computer Science'),
            ('Riti', 30, 'Delhi', 'Data Science'),
            ('Riti', 30, 'Delhi', 'Data Science'),
            ('Riti', 30, 'Mumbai', 'Information Security'),
            ('Aadi', 40, 'London', 'Arts'),
            ('Sachin', 30, 'Delhi', 'Medical')
            ]

test_df = pd.DataFrame(students, columns=['Name', 'Age', 'City', 'Subject'])

duplicateRowsDF = test_df[test_df.duplicated()]
```

Comment: How do you define `similar records` here? What is the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
df = df[df.duplicated(keep=False)]

df = df.groupby(list(df)).apply(lambda x: tuple(x.index)).tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

students = [('jack', 34, 'Sydeny', 'Engineering'),
            ('Sachin', 30, 'Delhi', 'Medical'),
            ('Aadi', 16, 'New York', 'Computer Science'),
            ('Riti', 30, 'Delhi', 'Data Science'),
            ('Riti', 30, 'Delhi', 'Data Science'),
            ('Riti', 30, 'Mumbai', 'Information Security'),
            ('Aadi', 40, 'London', 'Arts'),
            ('Sachin', 30, 'Delhi', 'Medical')
            ]

df = pd.DataFrame(students, columns=['Name', 'Age', 'City', 'Subject'])
print(df, '\n')

in_ind = 3
dup_df = df[(df['Name'] == df.iloc[in_ind, 0]) & (df['Age'] == df.iloc[in_ind, 1]) & (df['City'] == df.iloc[in_ind, 2]) & (df['Subject'] == df.iloc[in_ind, 3])]
print(dup_df)
```

Output:

```
     Name  Age      City               Subject
0    jack   34    Sydeny           Engineering
1  Sachin   30     Delhi               Medical
2    Aadi   16  New York      Computer Science
3    Riti   30     Delhi          Data Science
4    Riti   30     Delhi          Data Science
5    Riti   30    Mumbai  Information Security
6    Aadi   40    London                  Arts
7  Sachin   30     Delhi               Medical

   Name  Age   City       Subject
3  Riti   30  Delhi  Data Science
4  Riti   30  Delhi  Data Science
```